# Is there any alternate to TextView?

Tags: java, android

I m new to android application development. I made a project on getting feeds of sites. I displayed the title and description of feeds in textview which is not looking very presentable. Is there any alternate to it? I just need my application to look a bit presentable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for displaying a list of items.

Using a ListView would also let you set an onClick listener to let your users click the title/description and open the item.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want to style it with themes etc.

This is how to do this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

And I guess you already checked all the things you can do with a textview. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html